# Is there any benefit to using Py_DECREF instead of Py_XDECREF for Python C Extensions?

Tags: python, python-c-api, python-c-extension

I'm working through the Python C Extension documentation for defining new types and just finished the [Providing finer control over data attributes](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/newtypes.html#providing-finer-control-over-data-attributes) section.

In this section, they change the example code to ensure that the `first` and `last` attributes of the `Noddy` struct can never be `NULL`, for example by initializing the attributes to empty strings in `new` and adding getters and setters that raise `TypeError` if the user tries to delete or otherwise set these attributes to Null.

Additionally (and the point of my question), the author changes all of the `Py_XDECREF` to `Py_DECREF` for these attributes, stating that:

> With these changes, we can assure that the first and last members are never NULL so we can remove checks for NULL values in almost all cases. This means that most of the Py_XDECREF() calls can be converted to Py_DECREF() calls. The only place we can’t change these calls is in the deallocator, where there is the possibility that the initialization of these members failed in the constructor.

It seems to me that it would just be safer to use `Py_XDECREF`, given that `Py_DECREF` results in a `segmentation fault` if its passed a `NULL` value.

What is the benefit to using `Py_DECREF` over `Py_XDECREF`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you know that the object cannot be NULL, the benefits of `Py_DECREF` over `Py_XDECREF` are that:

- it is faster, since it avoids an unnecessary test and jump;
- it signals to the (human) reader that the pointer is expected to be non-NULL at the point of deallocation;
- it provides what is effectively a zero-cost assertion that the pointer is non-NULL - the program is likely to immediately crash if the invariant is broken.¹

These points can be important when dealing with low-level code, which is why Python core and most extensions are careful to only use `Py_XDECREF` (or `Py_CLEAR` in `tp_clear`) when the pointer can actually be NULL.

¹ Technically it's *undefined behavior*, which means that a crash is not guaranteed the way it would be with an actual assertion. In practice, however, the compiler has little choice but to generate code that dereferences the pointer, which will lead to a memory fault if it is NULL.